# How can i compare 2 arrays? if they both aren't same, system will switch the positions of the 2nd array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays

```
[
 "a",
 "b",
 "c"
]
```

and

```
[
  "c",
  "a",
  "b"
]
```

The system with compare both arrays and if these 2 arrays are not same, it will switch the positions of the 2nd array. for example:

```
[
 "a",
 "b",
 "c"
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please share the JavaScript code in which you have attempted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop to iterate over both the arrays and compare there indexes, then reassign the second array so that it matches the first. Using a single `if` statement to check if the indexes are indeed ordered differently and contain the same values.

```js
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let arr2 = ["c", "a", "b"];

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < arr1.length, j < arr2.length; i++, j++) {
  if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[j]) != j && arr2.includes(arr1[i])) {
    arr2 = arr1;
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

To address your second question of comparing an array of strings with an array of objects. You could iterate over both arrays and compare the index of each value with the `id` property in each object which stores the string. This gets the job done but a second layer of conditional check to make sure the second array contains each value within the first array would be ideal.

```js
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let arr2 = [{name: "Luna Rush", id: "c", games: "GTA 5"}, {name: "Davis Dyer", id: "a", games: "cricket"}, {name: "Anderson Vincent", id: "b", games: "PUBG"}];

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < arr1.length, j < arr2.length; i++, j++) {
  if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[j].id) != j) {
    // sort the second array (needs more work to match ordering of arr1)
    arr2.sort(function(a,b) { 
      let s1 = a.id.toLowerCase();
      let s2 = b.id.toLowerCase();
      if (s1 > s2) {
        return 1;
      } else if (s1 < s2) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: what if I have 2 arrays like
```
let arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let arr2 = [{id: "c"}, {id: "a"}, {id: "b"}];
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept if my answer helps with your original question. To address comparing an array of strings with another array of objects that is a slightly different question and solution.

Comment: @DynamoYT I added a second portion to address comparing one array of strings with an array of objects.

Comment: but if array 2 having more data with `id`, it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean? Yeah if array two has a different length than array one then it can't possible have the same number of indexes and therefore the reassignment wouldn't make sense. I'm happy to fix the second solution if you help me understand what isn't working.

Comment: the array is like that

let arr2 = [{name: "Luna Rush", id: "a", games: "GTA 5"}, {name: "Davis Dyer", id: "b", games: "cricket"}, {name: "Anderson Vincent", id: "c", games: "PUBG"}]

Comment: I added the array you included and it still works. Also, the way you ordered arr2 is the same order as arr1 ("a", "b", "c") so no reassignment or "switching" would take place. I added the same mismatched order ("c", "a", "b") as in the first example and the reassignment takes place so that arr2 matches the same order has arr1 ("a", "b", "c")

Comment: The issue is now that the objects themselves should be re ordered to match the same index as arr1 and not just have the id property changed. I used `.sort()` to sort the objects in arr2 by their `id` string values and this works to keep the `id`s with their respective objects and matches the order of arr1 indexes but thats only because arr1 is ordered like "a", "b", "c". It would take some more tinkering to move the objects to match indexes of arr1 if arr1 wasn't ordered in ascending order.

Comment: but that's not working in https://pastebin.com/raw/aZ2hDeYg

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere then. There is no reason it would work in the above snippet and not elsewhere. Also, in your pastebin link, your only logging the second array to the console. If you include a runnable snippet where it's not working (CodePen or JSFiddle) I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: In your pastebin link, you have typos in your object declaration. Your also including a completely different array than what you initially asked for with different properties `identifier` instead of `id` and id values with string and numeric values. Lastly, your problem is that you have  an extra trailing comma at the end of each object declaration in arr2 (after `uri` property) which is a syntax error. The commas need to separate each object, outside of the curly braces.

Comment: @DynamoYT After removing the syntax errors in your code (trailing commas after `uri` property) and using the same logic for the previous two solutions I provided you. It works fine. The arr1 and arr2 need to have the same length for reassignment to make sense though. Best of luck. I think I've provided you enough for you to finish the rest.